# Pass name to Subclass of UIView

Tags: iphone, object, uiview, uiscrollview, subclass

I have created a subclass of UIView in order to handle hitTest and Touches actions, as the UIView is a subview of a UIScrollview and I needed both the UIView and UIScrollView to be draggable.

I have got it 95% working - the subclassed UIView works perfectly if I jsut set a background colour - but if I set a subview with an image with transparanecy it doesn't always respond. I have some ideas on this so thats not the question.

My question is that as I have multiple instances of the subclassed UIView on the UIScrollview, how can i tell which one is dragged.

In a previous app I simply used;

```
if ([touch view] == blah)   {           
//do something;  
}  
else if ([touch view] == fred) {  
//do nothing;  
}
```

but as this sits in my main application .m file this was ok as blah and fred were both created there in viewdidload, but as the touch events in my code are captured in the subclass they don't know about blah and fred.

so 1) how do i let the subclass know about the items i've added - or -
2) how do i pass the name of the item through to the subclass in either hitTest or TouchesBegan - or -
3) is there a line of code to get the name of the current item

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone else who also has the same problem.

I found a simple solution:

In my viewDidLoad when I added the subclassed subviews, I just add in the line
customView1.tag = 111;

then in the subclass within my touches methods I can just use:
if ([touch view].tag == 111) {

Simple! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is how you could do it easily with NotificationCenter.

The object that needs to know which subview is dragged can listen to the notification named let's say "SubviewIsDragged" and each subview can send the notification "SubviewIsDragged" passing itself as a parameter.

This is the code:

Object that needs to know about dragging registers in it's init method the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(subviewIsDragged) name:@"SubviewIsDragged" object:nil];
```

Method that performs actions after dragging has been discovered:

```
-(void)subviewIsDragged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //Here you can get your subclass of UIView
    UIView* view = [notification object];

    // do what ever you want with the object
}
```

Now in your UIView subclass add the following to your dragging method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SubviewIsDragged" object:self];
```

Notice that you pass object "self" but you can pass any other object you want like NSString ID.

Hopes this help.

Answer (score 0):

add a panGesture recognizer to your subview class

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panPiece:)];
    [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [panGesture setDelegate:self];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

use this code for the translation and you wouldn't have any problems with dragging the wrong view

```
- (void)panPiece:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

[self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[self superview]];

    self.center = CGPointMake([self center].x + translation.x, [self center].y + translation.y);
    [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[self superview]];
}
}
```